# issue after change view controller Swift

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller

I have this code:

`start class`

```
self.registrazioneButton = myButton(frame: CGRectMake(30, 359+41, 290, 40), title: "Sign In")
self.registrazioneButton!.addTarget(self, action: "registrazioneButtonTap:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
self.view.addSubview(registrazioneButton!)

func registrazioneButtonTap(sender: AnyObject) { //Effettua login
    var registrazione : registrazioneViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("registrazione") as! registrazioneViewController
    defaultFunction.flipRightViewController(self, destinationViewController: registrazione, duration: 1.0)
}
```

`RegistrazioneViewController` is this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.registrazioneButton = myButton(frame: CGRectMake(30, 400, 290, 40), title: "Registrati")
    self.registrazioneButton!.addTarget(self, action: "registrazione", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    self.view.addSubview(registrazioneButton!)
}

func registrazione() {
      print("TEST")
}
```

`DefaultFunction` is this

```
private static func flipViewController(currentViewController: UIViewController, destinationViewController: UIViewController,
    duration: NSTimeInterval, typeTransiction: UIViewAnimationTransition) {

    UIView.beginAnimations("View Flip", context: nil)
    UIView.setAnimationDuration(duration)
    UIView.setAnimationTransition(UIViewAnimationTransition.FlipFromRight, forView: self.view, cache: false)
    UIView.setAnimationTransition(typeTransiction, forView: currentViewController.view, cache: true)
    currentViewController.removeFromParentViewController()
    currentViewController.view.addSubview(destinationViewController.view)
    UIView.commitAnimations()
}

public static func flipRightViewController(currentViewController : UIViewController , destinationViewController : UIViewController , duration : NSTimeInterval){
    flipViewController(currentViewController, destinationViewController: destinationViewController, duration: duration, typeTransiction: UIViewAnimationTransition.FlipFromRight)
}
```

My problem is that , the `registrazioneButton` in `RegistrazioneViewController` doesn't fire event when I tap up it( the method `registrazione()` and I don't understand why.

For change `view controller` from  `start class` to `RegistrazioneViewController` I use the method `flipRightViewController` in `DefaultFunction` class.

Where Do I wrong?

Comment: in the registrazione() I added print "TEST" and the function isn't executed , I didn't  add MyButton code because I use it in the other place of my code and it doesn't create problem. I use Flip Transition for change ViewController. If I don't use this flip , but for example PresentViewController it works fine

Comment: I tryed to add also a UIBarButtonItem( in the start class) and after Flip it don't work also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unclear what the desired design is, but `flipViewController` is not keeping the view controller hierarchy in sync with the view hierarchy. Because of this, the child's view controller would appear to be falling out of scope. And even if you kept it in scope some how (by adding your own strong reference to it), the view hierarchy would fall out of sync with the view controller hierarchy.

The easiest way present a second view controller with a flip animation would be:

```
let controller = storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Second")
controller.modalTransitionStyle = .FlipHorizontal
showViewController(controller, sender: self)
```

And when you dismiss it, it will flip back.

If you really want to present this as a subview of the current view using view controller containment, as your code snippet hints at, you need to do all of the containment calls necessary to keep the view hierarchy in sync with the view controller hierarchy. For example, if you wanted to add a view controller's view as a subview of another view, you might do something like:

```
let controller = storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Second")
addChildViewController(controller)
UIView.transitionWithView(containerView, duration: 0.5, options: .TransitionFlipFromRight, animations:
    {
        controller.view.frame = self.containerView.bounds
        self.containerView.addSubview(controller.view)
    }, completion: { finished in
        controller.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
})
```

Note, the sequence is:

- Instantiate child view controller
- Call `addChildViewController` on the parent view controller
- Add the subview, configuring and animating as you desire
- Call `didMoveToParentViewController` on the child view controller

And, as an aside, when you want to remove it, the sequence is:

- Call `willMoveToParentViewController(nil)` on the child view controller
- Remove the subview, animating this process as you desire
- Call `removeFromParentViewController()` on the child view controller

If this child view controller is taking over the full chrome, nowadays you'd probably stick with presenting the view controller as shown at the top of this answer. And if you didn't want to cover the whole screen, you'd engage in a custom `modalPresentationStyle`.

Answer (score -2):

Try this code below. Let me know if it work

```
self.registrazioneButton!.addTarget(self, action: "registrazione:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)

func registrazione(button: UIButton) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: No, that's not correct. You need the colon if the function has a parameter.

Comment: yeah I forgot.. tnx Rob